# upload file in html page via javascript that sets the filename

Tags: javascript, file-upload

In an html page I have input type='text' and a button

```
filename: [             ] 

[PUSH]
```

The user goes and fills the filename with "C:\test.txt" 
When the button is pushed, (onclick), I want to write some javascript to upload the file

(e.g.: c:\test.txt) and submit to the server.

Obviously the input type file would be hidden and programmatically edited.

is this doable or are there any limitations ?

The idea is that the user does not have to go and use the input type file and always go to the open dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the filename before upload. You must do this on the server. This is a security measure to prevent the browser from being able to upload arbitrary files.

Answer (score 0):

Your run of the mill javascript does not have access to the client's file system, and this is a good thing. Use the `type="file"` input that interfaces with the user's OS instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to enable to select filename from local disk and upload it without user selecting it first?

Then the answer is **no**. You cannot do that for security reasons, JS have no access to your local disks.

Also, you can't upload files via JavaScript, you need to have some server-side code to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For security reason you can not do this with JavaScript. But there exists a number of other upload tools (ex Java Applets, ActiveX  or Flash) web components that could "theoretically" do this.

I suggest that your search around for "File transfer java applet".

There is a Blog article that explains and compares some of those web upload components. Take a look at http://www.filecatalyst.com/comparison-of-web-based-file-transfer-methodologies